# Can a Edo Sapling Smart Contract, Emit a FA2 token? with the message from the payload_enc?

Tags: michelson

Can Edo Sapling Smart Contract, implement some kind of logic to emit a FA2 NFT ticket with metadata coming from the sapling message ?